# stop recvfrom() after certain time

Tags: c, sockets, udp, recvfrom

I wanna wait for a constant amount of time(like 3 seconds) for recvfrom() to receive some data, and I wanna exit my program if it didn't receive anything (in this 3 seconds)
how do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Call `setsockopt()` with the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option to set a read timeout on the socket. If the timeout fires, `recvfrom()` will return -1 with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`.